# Range of cells - each cell to be copied and pasted n number of times

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets in my workbook. Sheet1 had data till row 2000 already and Sheet2 had 4 new names. These 4 names has to be added into sheet1 from 2001th row 12 times each.

I tried the below code and stuck. On execution, I get the value of only first name appearing 12 times into sheet1 from 2001th row to 2013th row. My code is not working for the other three names.

```
Sub Add_new_names ()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer

    J = 1
    K = 1

    Do Until J > 12
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) + 1

    Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheets("Working").Cells(K, 4).Value

    J = J + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Subroutine doesn't find the values in any way for the "Working" sheet. You assign `K = 1` and it never changes which means when you are assigning the value in your `Do Until` loop it's always finding the value at `Sheets("Working").Cells(1, 4).Value`

You could write it as a nested `For...Loop` which will also increment your row counter like so:

```
Sub Add_new_names()

Dim i As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
Dim LastRowSheetOne As Long
Dim LastRowSheetTwo As Long


LastRowSheetTwo = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row

For K = 1 To LastRowSheetTwo
    For J = 1 To 12
        LastRowSheetOne = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(LastRowSheetOne, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(K, 4).Value
    Next J
Next K

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. That perfectly worked. Thanks Samuel for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Add_new_names ()

    Const NUM_RPT As Long = 12
    Dim k as Long

    For k = 1 to 4
        Activesheet.cells(rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).resize(NUM_RPT, 1).Value = _
                                                  Sheets("Working").Cells(k, 4).Value
    Next k
End Sub
```